# Что значит *this в c++?

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки, this

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x; 
        this->y = y;
    }
    void showCoords() 
    {
        std::cout << "Coords x: " << x << "\t y: " << y << std::endl;
    }
    Point &move(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x += x;
        this->y += y;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Я только начал изучать программирование. Мне не совсем понятно, зачем метод `move()` возвращает `*this`, если `this` - это уже ссылка на текущий объект. Я бы возвращал просто `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно было возвращать просто `this` если метод `move()` возвращал указатель.

```
Point* move(int x, int y)
{
    this->x += x;
    this->y += y;
    return this;
}
```

Но, это не очень удобно, так как, например-

```
Point obj;
obj.move(2,3)->showCoords();
```

нужно обращаться через стрелочку.  А если метод возвращал ссылку можно было б просто через точку-

```
Point obj;
obj.move(2,3).showCoords();
```

Если тип возврата ссылка - нужно `this` разыменовывать. Так как это указатель.

Answer (score 6):

`this` - не ссылка на текущий объект, а указатель. Поэтому, чтобы получился объект, указатель надо разыменовать - `*this`.

Comment: "чтобы получился объект" -> "чтобы получилась ссылка"

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы считаете, что *this вернет &Point?

Comment: Да, именно `Point&` он и вернёт. К тому же, у метода в коде именно такой тип.

Comment: Вы заблуждаетесь, он вернет lvalue типа Point - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388510/generally-is-dereference-pointer-expression-results-a-reference-type/48388647#48388647

Comment: А чем они отличаются?

Comment: В сносках ответа на en.SO есть ссылки на обсуждение этого вопроса, в частности, вот: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232